# Automatically add a newline when dragging text from browser into Neovim

Tags: neovim, mouse

One of my workflows is drag lines with the mouse from the browser to Neovim (Gnome Terminal) in insert mode.
What I'm trying to accomplish is putting a new line after dragging every line, without needing to type "Enter" manually.
I've done a lot of tries, but the problem seems to capture the event "drag-and-drop" in combination with autocmd.
I'd like to directly write a new line character, or call a function that writes a new line, or a macro, or whatever works. Doesn't have to be with autocmd.

I know Vim is meant to be used with the keyboard. I'm reasonably proficient with it, but I also want to be productive with the mouse.

BTW: I asked this question also on the emacs section. But I'm a big fan of Neovim also.